# Why are my pachysandra cuttings dying?

Tags: propagation, cuttings

I've never had issues rooting various plant cuttings in water. After a month of changing water almost daily and the cuttings in part sun, I lost half of my cuttings. I tried to root the remainder in soil but are seeing the same. What is causing this browning of leaves and near zero root growth?

[image: pao]